How to restrict access to AWS Express API via specific IP and have HTTPS certificate
I have an API on AWS that is restricted to only be accessed via my other AWS website domain (which sits on a different EC2 instance).
Currently this is over HTTP. When trying to create a certificate for it, either via letsencrypt or AWS, it won't work because it's not public.
Should I just allow HTTPS access to the API via all IPs: 0.0.0.0 and then restrict it further via the origin inside Nginx or Node.js?
Note: AWS gives a warning here:

Rules with source of 0.0.0.0/0 or ::/0 allow all IP addresses to access your instance. We recommend setting security group rules to allow access from known IP addresses only.

Yet the above warning is confusing because this other AWS document contradicts it by saying you need to enable HTTPS.
What is best practice?

"When trying to create a certificate for it, either via letsencrypt or aws, it won't work because its not public." This shouldn't be an issue for creating an AWS certificate. You just have to create a verification DNS record. AWS doesn't care if you use the issued certificate on something with a locked down security group. Please provide more details about what you have tried, and what errors or issues you encountered.

@MarkB Yes the aws cert I tried to issue is in a pending state. Though it will never show as success because its not currently public. How do I go about creating a verication dns record for an aws cert or other? Is this a record I add via route 53 on the api domain? and if so what do I put into it?

Amazon is not checking if the domain name is serving a public website. Amazon is waiting for you to create the DNS records required for validation that you own the domain name, that's all. It should say right in the AWS Certificate page in the AWS UI what records it is waiting for you to create. Please look at what it is telling you to do and read the instructions it is giving you on the screen.

@MarkB I've updated my question above - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate.html which says I need to enable https ( I assume on all 0.0.0.0). I just don't understand why the warning was there in the first place.

@MarkB - yes I can see those records - CNAMe _.23 etc... But typically I wouldn't need to add those records to route 53 hosted zone as it would automatically add them. Even If I add them to my api domain it doesn't change the pending state to success.

It doesn't add them to Route53 automatically in my experience. There is an extra step you have to take to make it add them. And that only works if Route53 is your actual DNS server for that domain. You have to add them to whatever your actual DNS server is. Once you add them it can take a while for the verification to happen, especially if you waited a long time to add them, instead of adding them as soon as it asked you to.

@MarkB Ah. You are right. It worked. It was just a delayed process. Adding the cname  manually to the host did indeed work. Thankyou. That's amazing. Next problem I have now is I cannot curl to that https location. Connection refused. Not sure If I need to add some extra https config to nginx

You can't use that AWS SSL certificate with Nginx. And the SSL certificate doesn't just "start working" as soon as it is created. You have to attach it to an AWS load balancer, cloudfront distribution, or API Gateway. Are you not using one of those?

@MarkB ah ok. Interesting. I have cloudfront for my main domain, but not the api. The api is running on nodejs, with reverse proxy on nginx on another ec2 instance. I'm not currently using aws api gateway. I wanted to keep it separate for more control and portability. Is it possible to have the aws api gateway connect to it or is that a waste of resource?

@MarkB I've decided against aws certification. Based on your suggestion to use a dns verification I've gone instead with lets encrypt and followed the steps on here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJPfdXN-dSc to use from my ec2 insteance with nginx: sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenge dns. thankyou

Thanks in part to @MarkB in comments and this guide I've found a solution using manual DNS record verification

Keep the restricted IP access from my other domain (don't have to make it open on all ports 0.0.0.0)

Use DNS record verification. From AWS EC2 instance, inside the terminal:
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenge dns

This creates a temporary DNS record, which I can add to route 53 hosted zone for the API.
_acme-challenge.api.MYDOMAIN
qmsLAetc....


Add that record to my hosted zone as type TXT:

_acme-challenge.api.MYDOMAIN  TXT  Simple  -  No  "uY-yYcETC...." 300


Inside terminal - press Enter to continue

chmod to the newly created SSL cert: sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live

Update Nginx to support SSL and redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name *.MYDOMAIN;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.MYDOMAIN/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  server_name *.MYDOMAIN.co.uk;


Test Nginx: sudo nginx -t

Restart Nginx: sudo systemctl restart nginx

Test HTTPS location: curl https://api.MYDOMAIN/healthcheck


It works!
